# Apply class to every 4th li inside a ul

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I need to display 4 li elements in a row, then apply a class="last" to every 4th li element.

right now i am doing like this,

```
var liCount = jQuery('.exploreContentArea .listArea ul li').size();
jQuery('.exploreContentArea .listArea ul li:eq(3)').addClass('last');
```

i need to apply the class to every 4th item of the ul.

Please help me on the same.

Thanks | Lokesh Yadav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nth-child`:

```
jQuery('.exploreContentArea .listArea ul li:nth-child(4n)')
.addClass('last').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just use the css-selector :)

```
.exploreContentArea .listArea ul li:nth-child(4n)
```

edit: [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)'s some more info on this :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `size()` to `length` as it's a bit faster I think because no function call. Sarfraz's answer is quite right.